# How to importing all active hosting servers as server list into blender game engine?

Tags: python, scripting, game-engine, import, logic-bricks

Hello I have a simple favor to ask that how can I import all active hosting servers IP address and Port address as a server list into blender game engine like multiplayer fps games like Call of Duty, Halo, Battlefield etc. There is no haste I can wait about till a month or more.
Please It will be a great favor for me for my small game project that I am currently working on. Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by "all active hosting servers". Servers from where?

Comment: I expect you would use [urllib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html#module-urllib.request) to get the list from a known server. To find players on the local network use something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21089268/2684771).

Comment: I mean if one or more people are hosting from a file such as host.blend, and others wan't to join as client but don't know the IP address or Port address, so they can join a specific IP address.

Comment: There is also a video on example youtube of what I'm trying to say:

Comment: This is impossible or at least not efficient possible. You need a server where game hosts can register themselves. This enables clients to get the hosts addresses from that server. This is typically combined with a lobby. The clients just need to know the address of the lobby server.

Comment: May be you are right, but there is a video on youtube which completely sums up my question: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mzLAoTJiz_g    Anyway I can totally understank if it is not possibe.

Answer (score 0):

To name a few, there are numerous, Python network modules out there, for example `socket`, `pickle` (and `cPickle`).